# Appcelerator Alloy data binding - transfrom is called twice?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have a collection with model `transform` function. I transform my model to the desired structure and return it.
To debug something I have printed out to console the item id.
This collection is binded to a `ListView` and in my controller I call the collection `fetch` method.
What I suddenly notice since I'm outputting the  item id to the console is that I see it running twice. This is my output:

```
[INFO] item.id = 51120f4b-a60b-4c46-a776-453e60faede3
[INFO] item.id = 874ba847-95eb-bb65-b1a5-4e8d8950bcf2
[INFO] item.id = 77590380-6045-6105-0604-e905807060ba
[INFO] item.id = 51120f4b-a60b-4c46-a776-453e60faede3
[INFO] item.id = 874ba847-95eb-bb65-b1a5-4e8d8950bcf2
[INFO] item.id = 77590380-6045-6105-0604-e905807060ba
```

You can see that each item is processed twice and they are processed in the same order. So I'm guessing I have some performance hit here due to the fact that it's running twice. Any explanation?

Looking more into it - the `read` operation from the db occurs only once. It's the `transform` method that is called twice.

Comment: Are you binding the same collection to two different listviews / tables?

Comment: @Newport99 No. Just regular binding to a `ListView`. I think I found a bug in the (at least) `properties` adapter that causes it. Also when modifying/adding/deleting a model in the collection it also causes the entire collection go throw the `transform` operation.